How do I prove the symmetry of the Hyperbolic metric on the Half-Plane?
Okay so the preamble I'm working with is that in the upper half-plane model of hyperbolic space, we are equipped with an inner product defined on a vector $v$ originating at the point $z=x+iy$ as: $\langle v,v\rangle_z:=\frac{1}{y^2}(v\cdot v)$.
The norm of the vector $v$ is then the norm induced by this inner product which is $\lVert v\rVert_z:=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle_z}$.
Then we generalize this to paths, saying that the arclength of a path $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{H}^2$ is defined as $L(\gamma):=\int_0^1\lVert\gamma'(t)\rVert_{\gamma(t)}dt$.
FINALLY we say oh by the way we use this to generate a proper metric defined as:
d$_{\mathbb{H}^2}(z,w):=inf${$L(\sigma)|\sigma\text{ is a path from }z\text{ to }w$}.
I can prove the non-negativity/point equivalence piece, and I don't have too much trouble with the triangle inequality proof either. But symmetry is sort of breaking my brain because I'm having a hard time conceptualizing a way to show that $L(\sigma(t))=L(\sigma(1-t))$ for $t\in[0,1]$, and that $\sigma(1-t)$ is the shortest path from $w$ to $v$. Any help would be HUGELY appreciated.

The question you're asking has nothing to do with the hyperbolic metric. It’s true in complete generality. Just turn one integral into the other.

@TedShifrin Thank you, I felt like I was missing some fundamental understanding of path computation here. Do you think you could elaborate?

If $\sigma^-(t)=\sigma(1-t)$, write down the integrals giving $L(\sigma)$ and $L(\sigma^-)$ and show they are equal.

@TedShifrin help with how to "show are they equal" is quite literally what I was looking for in my OP, writing down the integral wasn't enough for me because I was missing information on how paths work (just like I said in my comment to you), but all good I got the answer somewhere else. Path derivatives are independent of direction and in the upper half-plane the imaginary part is invariant under path reversal and also while the integration wouldn't necessarily be equal, because we're talking about distance we can ignore the negative to account for that inequality. Thanks for your time!

I think you should be able to differentiate $\sigma$ and $\sigma^-$ and make a substitution to show the integrals are equal. What you’ve written is not too meaningful. Make an effort to do the steps.

@TedShifrin that's a cool opinion. The substitution I believe you are referring to is something I would have had no concept of without knowing that the derivative of a path and the derivative of its inverse are equal, because that explains how the numerators in both integrals are equal. And I would have needed to know that complex line part of the path's parametric equation is invariant under reversal to know why the denominators of the integrals can be considered equivalent. Thank goodness I found that information somewhere else, cause it seems like you don't even see meaning in it.

Criticizing someone offering you help isn’t the way to go here. If you don’t understand or believe someone’s answer, it’s more effective to think about why the answer is unsatisfactory and then follow up with questions. We don’t want to just hand you the answer directly. Our assumption here is that you’re trying to learn math. Our experience is that it’s better to provide guidance to help you find the answer on your own. What @TedShifrin is telling you is that you don’t need anything more than the properties of ann integral to prove symmetry. Geometric meaning of integral doesn’t matter.

@Deane that's a very kind and balanced response, I appreciate you taking the time to write it out. I suppose I wouldn't have been so critical if the 1st comment Ted left hadn't been "just turn one integral into the other", which is... the step I was already asking about. I suppose it was helpful of him to say that the question had "nothing to do with the hyperbolic metric", so I responded kindly asking him to elaborate, and his response was "show they're equal", which again, was what I was already asking about? I hope you would agree that it's a tad generous to call that "guidance"?

@TedShifrin's second comment explains more precisely what he meant by "turn one integral into the other". "that's a cool opinion", as well as the rest of your comment, is rather dismissive, especially since he was not offering an opinion. He was offering concrete mathematical advice on how you could work out the answer to your question. It's OK not to understand immediately someone's suggestion, but you should devote some time to thinking about it before asking for more guidance. A dismissive response is a good way not to learn the math and discourage people from being helpful in the future.

@Deane his third comment included an opinion that what I had written was "not very meaningful", which is the opinion I was referring to. If $you$ think that this was "concrete mathematical advice" and not an opinion, then $I$ think that's $your$ opinion, which you are welcome to have. He also indicated I should "Make an effort to do the steps" which is an interesting thing to add after I said, thrice, that I had written out the integrals but was missing an understanding of how the computational characteristics of path reversal would let me alter them to be equal. Tbh, I felt dismissed??

I suggest you try to understand his second comment and do the calculation as best as you can. If you still get stuck, show us how far you got and we'll try to help you further.

@Deane well as far as I know I got the answer, just not from here, but I'll elaborate bc we all know the more proof-readers, the better, so correct me if I'm wrong: The numerator within the integral is the sqr rt of the sums of the sqrs of the derivatives of the parametric eq'ns forming the pths. These are equal bc pth derivation is indep. of direction. Then the denominators have the imaginary coord's parametric eq'n squared. These are equal bc they are indep. of pth reversal. Lastly, reversing a pth usually makes the resulting int. negative, but we ignore this bc we're talking magnitude. Yes?

That's not a mathematically precise explanation. You have to translate your words into a proper mathematical proof, which requires writing everything using mathematical notation, before I can say whether your answer is correct or not. That's what Ted meant by "Make an effort to do the steps." And your attempted answer mentions many things that are irrelevant to proof of symmetry. That's what Ted meant by "What you’ve written is not too meaningful." It sounds like an opinion, but he's trying to help you focus on what matters and ignore what doesn't.

@Deane well unfortunately the character limit meant that's the best I could do. What I wrote is a pretty exact description of the terms involved, but sure. I'll try to add the actual variables instead of their names to the answer later when I have more time to waste. Thanks for your notes on my question and notes on the tone of my replies.

Path derivatives are independent of direction and in the upper half-plane the imaginary part is invariant under path reversal and also while the integration wouldn't necessarily be equal, because we're talking about distance we can ignore the negative to account for that inequality. All of that should be enough to show the two integrals are equivalent.

Isn’t that going backwards? The distance function is defined as an integral. It is asserted that the distance function is symmetric. That therefore implies the integral is symmetric. That’s not a proof. It’s trusting that the person making the assertion is correct.

@Deane I'm trying to prove that the integral I have satisfies the conditions of the distance function. So while I am sort of going backwards, it's just because it's a definition proof. So when I write out the integrals to compute the proof, I need to have the above 3 things to assert that the two integrals are equal. Let me know if that sounds wrong to you though?
